# Suppose $P(A) = 0.4$, $P(A \cup B) = 0.7$, $P(B) = p$. For which value of $p, A$ and $B$ will be independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Being $A$ and $B$ two events. Suppose that $P(A) = 0.4$ while $P(A \cup B) = 0.7$ and $P(B) = p$.

The question is: For which value of $p, A$ and $B$ will be independents?

The solution says it is: $7/4$, but I can only see $p= 3/6$

My answer:
$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$
$=0.7 = 0.4 + p - [P(A)\cdot P(B)]$
$=0.7 = 0.4 + p -0.4p$
$=0.3 = 0.6p \implies \,p = 3/6 $

Comment: It obviously can't be $7/4 > 1$, since it's a probability.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. The solution might be wrong.

Comment: $3/6$ is correct, but you may want to simplify it a bit more and write $1/2$.

Comment: Use `$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$` to show $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, consider giving [check marks](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Pr(A)=0.4$ and $Pr(A\cup B)=0.7$

Let $Pr(B)=p$ for some yet unknown value of $p$.  We wish to find what value of $p$ works so that $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

By definition of independent events, we would require that $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$

By inclusion-exclusion, we have that $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cup B)$

Combining this information and plugging in values, we have:

$Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cup B)=0.4p = 0.4+p-0.7$

implying $0.6p = 0.3$ and that $p = \frac{1}{2}$

---

As mentioned above already in comments, an answer of $p=\frac{7}{4}$ makes no sense when we are talking about probabilities since one of the axioms of probability implies that $0\leq Pr(E)\leq 1$ for all events $E$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)